# Issue in showing tiff image in browser

Tags: html, image, tiff

I am facing problem in showing tiff images.  My html code is below:

```
< img src="tiffdocument.tif" />
```

Comment: Make sure you can access the image. If you can get to your page at `file:\\C:\Users\john\Desktop\index.html` then you should be able to see your image at `file:\\C:\Users\john\Desktop\tiffdocument.tif` in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

TIFF is not a "web friendly" format. The only formats you can use reliably are GIF, PNG and JPEG.

Comment: David is correct.  Actually, no browser can support TIF files ( I think it has to do with licensing ).  What I would do is write an HTTP service that dynamically converts a TIF to a PNG and put the URL of that service as the <img src="...">

Answer (score 0):

Will you able to see other images such as .png, .gif, .jpeg etc ?

Is your image path is correct ?

there must not be space between `<` and `tagname`

```
< img src="tiffdocument.tif" />
```

should be

```
<img src="tiffdocument.tif" />
```

Comment: what will you get instead of image?check my edited answer?